# How can I align perfectly 4 topo sheets?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have 4 topo sheets and i want then to align perfectly [image]

Would I have to georeference each image again? Or is there a more simple method?

Comment: why not use wms in qgis?

Comment: will look into that, never really used it before, thanks

Comment: Try http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS in QGIS Add Layer >WMS

Comment: "Perfect" alignment is okay as a goal, though sometimes not obtainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some raster, You could to merge those, 
You have some tools.
First, in raster menu (Miscellaneous - Merge...)
Second, in processing plugin -- SAGA --> Grid Tools --> Mosaic raster layer